# Angular. Router DI not working when using APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-di

I'm preloading app configuration from server with `APP_INITIALIZER` in following way, `AppModule`:

```
providers: [
    ConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: configServiceFactory,
      deps: [ConfigService],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
```

Then, `ApiService` injected manually from `ConfigService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

  private api: ApiService;

  public constructor(
    private injector: Injector
  ) {

    // Avoid cyclid dependencies, inject manually:
    this.api = injector.get(ApiService);
  }
```

And finally `router` is undefined when injected in `ApiService`

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptionsArgs, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private http: Http
  ) {

    console.log(router, 'router'); // undefined
    debugger;
```

[image]

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ogCHjeYuCDM8vNLdwAFx?p=preview)

Any thoughts how could it be fixed / worked around ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works works in anguler 4

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, Provider, Injector } from '@angular/core';

export function appInitializerFactory(
    injector: Injector
): () => Promise<any> {
    return () => {
        return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const router = injector.get(Router);
                // do stuff
                resolve(this.config);
            });
        });
    }
}

export const appInitializerProvider: Provider = {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
    deps: [
        Injector
    ],
    multi: true
};
```

Comment: While I get the Router this way, the initialization seems to fall in an endless loop with the setTimeout...

Comment: I saw that it did not work in your plunger,
But I could make it work through.

src/app.ts: 31 ->  RouterModule.forRoot(), to RouterModule.forRoot([]),