# Angular routes added at startup from http response, not registered

Tags: angular, routes

I have followed this answer as guide to load routes from backend:

[Angular 5 Build routes from API data at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953281/angular-5-build-routes-from-api-data-at-startup)

and after I done it I have new routes from responses added to `router.config` as they should be but for some case I can't access them when I enter added path from http response I get an error:
`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'`, but when I log router.config there is such a path  properly configured.

Any ideas why is that happening in Angular 11 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is this declaration:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation: 'enabled',
```

where I used `initialNavigation: 'enabled'` for SSR, please comment if u know how to combine SSR with loading routes from API.