# Angular combine SSR with loading routes

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, server-side-rendering

I went through answer from this question [Angular 5 Build routes from API data at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953281/angular-5-build-routes-from-api-data-at-startup) as a guide to load routes from backend, then I noticed that I can't navigate to those routes, that I loaded to routerConfig from API.

I found the reason for that and it turned out that my application is using server site rendering so I have `initialNavigation` set as  'enabled' and thats the reason that my routes not being registered.
Docs says: "This value is required for server-side rendering to work."

I need solution to load routes from API while keeping SSR since app needs to be SEO friendly, is there is a good solution to do that ? as I am googling for a while and can't find anything usefull in those circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example service to load your external routes.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouteConfigService {

  constructor(
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

  public loadRoutes(): Promise<any> {
    var promise = this.categoryService.list().then(t => {

      const config = this.router.config;
      config.push({ path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' });

      t.forEach(category => {
          config.push({ path: category.url, component: CategoryComponent });
      });

      this.router.resetConfig(config);

    });
    return Promise.resolve(promise);
  }
}
```

And then your app-routing.module.ts should look something like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([])],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (routeConfigService: RouteConfigService) => 
        () => routeConfigService.loadRoutes(),
      deps: [RouteConfigService],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```